# How to prepend text to the_content, but after img/shortcode

Tags: filters, the-content

I was trying to add some text to the beginning of every post (the text comes from `post_meta`, but for this example let's assume it's static text).

Here's what I tried:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
    return 'Text from meta - ' . $content;
});
```

However, if the post starts with a - usually floated - image (sometimes even wrapped in a caption shortcode), the added text will come before the image.

I would like for the text to be prepended to the first paragraph in the post. Is there any way to accomplish this without parsing the full HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled on using a regex, with a limit of 1 so it only happens on the first paragraph:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>/', '$1Text from meta - ', $content, 1);
    return $content;
});
```