# How do I add the featured image to the_content after the first paragraph?

Tags: post-thumbnails, filters, the-content

**My problem:**

I'm trying to create a filter that will add the featured image of a post to the_content, so that I can have the first paragraph of the_content displayed before this image.

**What I basicly want to achieve:**

```
<p>First Paragraph of the_content</p>
<img>The Post's Featured Image</img>
<p>The rest of the_content</p>
```

I someone is able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the 'the_content' filter:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image', 20 );

function insert_featured_image( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );
    return $content;
}
```

Of course, you can add options to the the_post_thumbnail() function to define which size of thumbnail you'd like to use, etc... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Hmm, it's inserting the featured image yes, but not after the first paragraph?

Comment: Modified to re-add the closing </p> -- if you can provide a URL, I'd be happy to take a peek, otherwise can you post the actual HTML being outputted?

Comment: Also, needs get_the_post_thumbnails and not the_post_thumbnail as the original code showed. Oops. ;-)

Comment: Did you update with the most recent code change above?  I accidentally used the_post_thumbnail when I should have used get_the_post_thumbnail, which might have caused your problem.

Comment: Edit: Yes I did. -- Oh, hehe. Hmm well now it isn't showing the image at all. :P

Comment: Just for giggles, made one little change.  Blind troubleshooting. 8-)

Comment: I got your solution working! I added this `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single')` which did the trick. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: Doh! ;-)  Wasn't thinking.  Updated my answer for future searchers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically the quickest solution would be to use a shortcode in your content.  Otherwise you'll need a good handle on regex to dump the image between paragraphs using a filter.

Best way would be to add this to functions.php

```
<?php 

function featured_image($post) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->id))
        the_post_thumbnail('large');
}

add_shortcode('featured_image', 'featured_image');
?>
```

After your first paragraph in the content just type `[featured_image]`.

Comment: This would definitely be the quickest way yes, but the site is for a client, so I'm afraid this isn't a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note -

Using some kind of regex matching you can do this. Here's one of them. Just drop in this snippet in yout theme's `functions.php` file so that it will print content of variable `$img` just after first paragraph (i.e. after first occurrence of `</p>` tag) in your post content.

passing current posts thumbnail / featured image value to $img will print that image after first paragraph.

```
// Goes into functions.php file
// Adds $img content after after first paragraph (!.e. after first `</p>` tag)
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
   $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
   $img = '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="" title=""/>';
   $content = preg_replace('#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1'.$img, $content, 1);
   return $content;
});
```

<sup>Modified [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38663/17968) to append variable after first paragraph.</sup>

Comment: I had to change '$1' to '$2' to get it to show the `<div>My Image html</div>` after the first paragraph - I have obviously no idea why?


How do I replace `<div>My Image html</div>` with `the_post_thumbnail('post-single')`? If I just insert the_post_thumbnail('post-single') it shows the image before the first paragraph unlike if I insert a random <div>.

Comment: it worked perfect on myside, btw updated my code to show featured image.

Comment: Yay, it worked! :) Thanks a lot (I still had to change '$1' to '$2' though.

Comment: instead 'large' use this - 'thumbnail' also make sure you [added theme support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support)

Answer (score 1):

To customise the number of paragraphs before the featured image, I adapted the above answer and adapted the code from an ad placement solution.

To use: Add the following two snippets to functions.php and customise the numeral where indicated to control the number of paragraphs.

```
// Adds $featured_img and $caption after n paragraph

add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image' );

function insert_featured_image( $content ) {
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
            $caption = get_the_post_thumbnail_caption( $post );
        } else {
            $caption = '';
        }
    $featured_image = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ) . '</div>'.'<div>' . $caption . '</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $featured_image, 2, $content ); // The numeral here controls the number of pars. Customise it to your needs
    }
}

return $content;
}

// Parent function

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) 
{
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }

    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
}
 
return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is Simple Process to Done it. Follow Simple Step.

- Login to Your Website and Go To Dashboard On WordPress.
- Go To Appearance>Theme File Editor>Theme Functions (functions.php)
- Paste This Code.

```
// Adds $featured_img and $caption after n paragraph
    
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image' );
    
function insert_featured_image( $content ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                }
        $featured_image = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ) . '</div>'.'<div>' . $caption . '</div>';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
            return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $featured_image, 2, $content ); // The numeral here controls the number of pars. Customise it to your needs
        }
    }
    
    return $content;
}
    
    // Parent function
    
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) 
{
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
    
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
    
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
     
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as [TheWiseOldElf's code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/400670), except you've deleted the lines that set $caption, so now you're using an undefined variable. Can you explain why you've made that change - does it help? (I can't imagine it does.) Why post the same code again?