# Add 'if exists' to filter

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails

This almost perfectly fixed an issue I had: [How do I add the featured image to the_content after the first paragraph?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61272/how-do-i-add-the-featured-image-to-the-content-after-the-first-paragraph)

However, if there isn't a featured image, the code still outputs a blank `<img src alt title>` after the first paragraph, and creates a white space.

Any ideas how I can change this code, so it checks **if** there's a featured image and if so, places it after the first paragraph - but if there isn't a featured image, doesn't do anything?

Thanks so much in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

You want [`has_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail).

```
add_filter( 'the_content', insert_featured_image, 20 );
function insert_featured_image( $content ) {
  global $post;
  if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Note: The code above is from the [post referenced in the OP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61272/how-do-i-add-the-featured-image-to-the-content-after-the-first-paragraph), but with the `has_post_thumbnail` conditional. I also had to add `global $post;` to avoid the "undefined variable" `Notices`s. Alternately, you can leave that `$post` references out as `has_post_thumbnail` and `get_the_post_thumbnail` will assume the global `$post` (which is why the original code works at all).

```
add_filter( 'the_content', insert_featured_image, 20 );
function insert_featured_image( $content ) {
  if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail(null, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: If this solved the problem please mark it "accepted". Look for the check mark on the left.